# Integration of razorpay with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, payment, razorpay

I am building a website in which users have to subscribe to one of the given plans, and I want to collect money from them using RazorPay.

Now I haven't used any payment services like Stripe, Razorpay, or anything like that. This is the first time I am working on that, so I need some guidance regarding that.

How can I setup razorpay on the backend side?(The front end is in flutter).

Additionally, I want to save the payments data in the database as well.

The route to subscribe the package:

```
exports.subscribe_package = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const razorPay = new RazorPay({
      key_id: keys.razorPayKey,               //Basic razorpay set-up
      key_secret: keys.razorPaySecret,
   });

    const payment = await paymentService.getPayment(
      req.data.id,
      req.body.razorpay_id
    );
    const subscription = await subscribeService.addSubscriberPackage(
      req.data.id,
      req.params.id
    );
    const user_data = await userService.addPackage(
      req.data.id,
      req.params.id,
      subscription._id
    );
    return res.succeed(user_data);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.failed(500, "Internal Server Error", error);
  }
});
```

It is nothing but the updating of some data in the database and the set-up of basic razorpay things.

The currency will be "INR".

**The front-end side will send the paymentID to the backend. I just want to make use of it to capture the payment if it is successful or not.
How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

```
const Razorpay = require('razorpay');

const instance = new Razorpay({ key_id: 'id', key_secret: 'secret' });
let response = await instance.payments.capture('PaymentID', '2121', 'INR')
if(response){
  // save the payments data
  return res.success({ data: response });
}else{
 return res.failed({ data: {},message:"payment captured failed." });
}
```

Comment: How can I get the PaymentID and I am getting an error of api key provided is invalid. I am running on the test mode